# Openssl issue while installing apache 2.4.23

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, openssl, httpd

I'm trying to install apache2.4.23 on centos 6.8 and i'm getting this :

```
ab.c: In function 'main':
ab.c:2398: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SSLv2_client_method'
ab.c:2398: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
ab.c:2412: warning: 'TLSv1_1_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1604)
ab.c:2414: warning: 'TLSv1_2_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1610)
ab.c:2417: warning: 'TLSv1_client_method' is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1598)
ab.c:2468: warning: implicit declaration of function 'CRYPTO_malloc_init'
/usr/share/apr-1/build/libtool --silent --mode=link gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2 -pthread   -L/opt/httpd-2.4.25/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread  \
                 -o ab  ab.lo      /usr/lib64/libaprutil-1.la -ldb-4.7 -lexpat -ldb-4.7 /usr/lib/libapr-1.la -lrt -lcrypt -lpthread -lm
ab.o: In function `main':
/opt/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:2468: undefined reference to `CRYPTO_malloc_init'
/opt/httpd-2.4.25/support/ab.c:2398: undefined reference to `SSLv2_client_method'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ab] Erreur 1
make[2]: quittant le répertoire « /opt/httpd-2.4.25/support »
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Erreur 1
make[1]: quittant le répertoire « /opt/httpd-2.4.25/support »
make: *** [all-recursive] Erreur
```

I tried installing openssl 1.1.0 and reconfigure the installation of apache with :

```
./configure --enable-layout=admin --enable-mpms-shared=all  --with-ssl=/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Still getting the same problem, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of documentation i found that the problem was in `openssl version`, in my case i was using openssl 1.1.x so when httpd 2.4.23 was released openssl 1.1.0 was still beta, i installed openssl 1.0.2j and i compiled apache with :

`./configure --with-apr=/usr/local/apr/bin --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/bin/`